# Can you use '死にました' for things other than people?

Tags: word-choice

I know that usually, when you talk about someone dying, you say, 'なくなりました' to be polite and, '死にました' to literally just say they died.

So, I was wondering if you could use 死にました for things other than people, such as for animals or plants as なくなりました would probably sound a bit strange?

Comment: Actually shouldn't it be いなくなりました, as one would be using 居るinstead of 有る when talking about a human?

Comment: @Chewie, the verb is 亡くなる, which is an inflection of 亡い which means dead. It is related to the word 無い "nonexistent", but it's its own word.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, long story short is that you *can* say that, but it may sound [a little unnatural](https://hinative.com/en-US/questions/1045363).

The post above references using なくなる, but it does give relevant answers to your question:

For plants: 「枯れる」 - "to wither", for animals: 「死んでしまう」 - "to die/pass away", for people: 「死んでしまう／亡くなる」 - "to die/pass away".

Comment: The OP's question wasn't about whether you could use 亡くなる but rather about whether you could use 死ぬ for things other than people.

Comment: It was, wasn't it? Let me fix that...

Comment: Jisho.org lists 枯れる as meaning both "wither" and "die." Something can wither without dying and die without withering. Is there a word that could specifically refer to a plant's dying?